# O que é um git diff, como fazer e para o que serve?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github, diff

estou com um problema no meu projeto.

Faço contribuições para um projeto do git, e ao verificar a branch Master, vi que está faltando alguns métodos que tem em uma branch, mas não tem na Master. Não sei dizer quantos e quais são esses métodos, por isso acredito que seria bom fazer um DIFF entre branchs, porém, não sei se é o certo a se fazer para resolver esse problema e também não sei a sintax correta para isso. Outro pontp é, um comando DIFF vai resolver essa divergência entre branchs? Em algum momento do desenvolvimento e commits, esses métodos se perderam, por alguns conflitos que surgiu, são muitas pessoas atualizando as mesmas classes. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe para o diff entre branches é:

```
$ git diff origin/[branch1]..origin/[branch2]
```

O diff não vai resolver a divergência, apenas vai mostrar a diferença entre eles. Para resolver você poderá fazer um merge dos branches ou um rebase e ir resolvendo os conflitos nos arquivos.

Caso você precise consultar o histórico de alterações de algum arquivo, pode executar o comando:

```
$ git log -p caminho/do/arquivo
```

Voce ainda pode usar o [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) do git para restaurar arquivos em commits específicos.

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado, com certeza ja ajudou bastante.

Aproveitando a gentileza, gostaria de mais uma informação. Um DIFF lista a diferença entre as branchs? Pq minha ideia é pegar a diferença entre as branchs, alterar qualquer coisa nessas classes, commitar elas e abrir um merge request, para subir essas atualizações na branch Master. Visto que, no merge request, só é mergeado o que foi alterado/atualizado desde o último merge aberto, ou seja, coisas que não tiveram alteração. não são mergeadas nem commitadas.